# Android Jetpack Compose: VM not updating data structure when modified

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I’ve got a problem with a LazyColumn of elements that have a favourite button: basically when I tap the favourite button, the item that is being favourited (a document in my case) is changed in the underlying data structure in the VM, but the view isn’t updated, so I never see any change in the button state.

```
class MainViewModel(private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO) : ViewModel() {
    var documentList = emptyList<PDFDocument>().toMutableStateList()
    ....
    fun toggleFavoriteDocument(pdfDocument: PDFDocument) {
        documentList.find {
            it == pdfDocument
        }?.let {
            it.favorite = !it.favorite
        }
    }
}
```

The composables are:

```
@Composable
fun DocumentRow(
    document: PDFDocument,
    onDocumentClicked: (String, Boolean) -> Unit,
    onFavoriteValueChange: (Uri) -> Unit
) {
    HeartIcon(
        isFavorite = document.favorite,
        onValueChanged = { onFavoriteValueChange(document.uri) }
    )
}

@Composable
fun HeartIcon(
    isFavorite: Boolean,
    color: Color = Color(0xffE91E63),
    onValueChanged: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    IconToggleButton(
        checked = isFavorite,
        onCheckedChange = {
            onValueChanged()
        }
    ) {
        Icon(
            tint = color,
            imageVector = if (isFavorite) {
                Icons.Filled.Favorite
            } else {
                Icons.Default.FavoriteBorder
            },
            contentDescription = null
        )
    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong? because when I call the `toggleFavouriteDocument` in the `ViewModel`, I see it’s marked or unmarked as favorite but there is no recomposition at all anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing it because you didn't post the rest of your code, but your `documentList` in the VM isn't observable, so how would the Composable know that it got changed? It needs to be something like `Flow` or `LiveData`, and it needs to be observed in the Composable. Something like this:

in ViewModel:

```
val documentList = MutableLiveData<List<PDFDocument>>()
```

in Composable:

```
val documentList by viewModel.documentList.observeAsState(List<PDFDocument>())
```

And you'll probably have to change the way you modify items in `documentList`. LiveData is weird about mutable collections inside MutableLiveData, and modifying individual items doesn't trigger a state change. You have to create a copy of the list with the modified items, and then re-port the whole list to the LiveData variable:

```
fun toggleFavoriteDocument(pdfDocument: PDFDocument) {
    documentList.value?.let { oldList ->
        // create a copy of existing list
        val newList = mutableListOf<PDFDocument>()
        newList.addAll(oldList)
        
        // modify the item in the new list
        newList.find {
            it == pdfDocument
        }?.let {
            it.favorite = !it.favorite
        }
        // update the observable
        documentList.postValue(newList)
    }        
}
```

**Edit**: There's also a potential problem with the way that you're trying to update the favorite value in the existing list. Without knowing how `PDFDocument` is implemented, I don't know if you can use the `=` operator. You should test that to make sure that `newList.find { it == pdfDocument }` actually finds the document